# How to cut out a drop shadow inside the container?

Tags: wpf, xaml

The idea is to create a 2.5D effect like this

```css
DIV {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
  z-index:1;
  position:absolute;
  }

P{
  top:83px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:0;
  }
```

```html
<div>I appear to be layered on top</div>

<p>Ey! Get off me!</p>
```

So basically a shadow around a semi-transparent rectangle. However, the dropshadow effect in WPF does not look the same as box-shadow in CSS. For one, it shadows actual opaque things that its applied on, not just a box around it. To get around that, I tried applying it on just a border like this

```
    <Border BorderThickness="1px" BorderBrush="Black">
        <Border.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0"></DropShadowEffect>
        </Border.Effect>
    </Border>
```

But its still different in 2 ways

1. The visible border - thats OK, I can incorporate it into the shadow by playing with the opacity
2. The shadow is also cast on the inside of the border - not Ok, it destroys the illusion and I don't know how to fix it

Would it be possible to somehow cut out the effect on the inside of the container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the borders `Background`to white the inside shadow of the border disappears. Now you could wrap the `Border` and a `TextBlock` inside a canvas and change the opacity of the canvas. Then you also need to specify the `ZIndex` for the canvas to overlay other controls.

[image]

Here is the code for this example:

```
    <Grid>
        <Canvas Name="Canvas" Width="100" Height="100" Grid.ZIndex="1" Opacity="0.8" >      
            <Border BorderThickness="1px" BorderBrush="Black" Background="White"
                    Height="{Binding ElementName=Canvas, Path=Height}" 
                    Width="{Binding ElementName=Canvas, Path=Width}">
                <Border.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0"></DropShadowEffect>
                </Border.Effect>
            </Border>
            <TextBlock Foreground="Black" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"
                       Width="{Binding ElementName=Canvas, Path=Width}"
                       Text="I appear to be layered on top"/>
        </Canvas>

        <TextBlock FontSize="25" Width="180" Height="50" Text="Ey! Get off me!" 
                    Margin="185,174,152,96"/>
    </Grid>
```